# Eigenspaces of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume $A$ and $B$ are symmetric $n \times n$ matrices and consider the following block matrix
$$
T = \begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
B & A
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Let $z = (u,v) \in \mathbb R^{2n}$ be a (column) vector partitioned into two $n \times 1$ vectors $u$ and $v$. Assuming that $(u,v)$ is an eigenvector of $T$, can we related $u$ and $v$ to eignevectors of $A$ and $B$ or some other known eigenproblem in $(A,B)$? For example, are they related to the generalized eigenvalue problem $A x = B \lambda x$?

Writing out the condition $T  z = \gamma z$ in block form and summing the two equations, for example, gives this: For any eigenvector $z = (u,v)$ of $T$, $u+v$ is an eigenvector of $A+B$. What more can we say along these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing out what it means to have $T z = \lambda z$, we get
$$ \eqalign{A u + B v &= \lambda u\cr
            B u + A v &= \lambda v\cr}  \tag{1}$$
i.e.
$$ \eqalign{B u &= (\lambda I - A) v\cr
   B v &= (\lambda I - A) u\cr} $$
If $B$ is invertible, this implies
   $u = B^{-1}(\lambda I - A) v = (B^{-1}(\lambda I - A))^2 u$
and similarly $v = (B^{-1}(\lambda I - A))^2 v$.

Conversely, if $B^{-1}$ is invertible and we have a nonzero vector $u$ such that
$u = (B^{-1}(\lambda I - A))^2 u$, taking $v = B^{-1} (\lambda I - A) u$ we get (1).

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting. I guess nothing more can be said beyond this point? So there would be a characteristic equation like this: $\det[ I - (B^{-1}(\lambda I - A))^2] = 0$ which does not look very familiar.